# Does AWS CDK create default stack name in CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Using CloudFormation template, CloudFormation service ask for a stack name(`AWS::StackName`) before  applying the template.

Using AWS CDK, we run `cdk synth` to create cfn template & `cdk deploy` to deploy services based on the template.

Does AWS CDK create default stack name in Cloudformation service? after running `cdk deploy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to create a stack you have to instantiate an object for that stack. When you do, you pass the stack name as a parameter. Example in Python:

```py
class MyStackClass:
    (...)

# You have to have an app
app = core.App()
# Here's the stack
MyStack = MyStackClass(app, "StackName")
```

Other than that, see [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/stacks.html):

> The physical names of the AWS CloudFormation stacks are automatically determined by the AWS CDK based on the stack's construct path in the tree. By default, a stack's name is derived from the construct ID of the Stack object, but you can specify an explicit name using the stackName prop, as follows.
>
> ```
> new MyStack(this, 'not:a:stack:name', { stackName: 'this-is-stack-name' });
> ```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000872/does-cdk-perform-orchestration-apart-from-provisioning